# Panic in the while loop instead of stopping when condition is met

Tags: while-loop, rust

I'm trying to write very simple parser in Rust. I have a `while` loop which just checks if end of input was reached by comparing current position in the source with the length of the source, but instead of stopping when the end of input is reached (more specifically, `end_of_input` being set to `true`), it keeps going and reaches the part where I read the character at the current position. Since that position is the same as the length of the source, I'm receiving panic and I can't see where I made a mistake in the logic (when I add `break` the last token is not added to the vector of tokens).

Here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21463cc72219fda858ad7fc62ac7e936). I'm using `regex` 1.3.9.

```
use regex::Regex;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum TokenType {
    CommandOperator,
    Keyword(String),
    Str(String),
    Const(String)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Token {
    token_type: TokenType,
    start_position: usize,
    end_position: usize,
}

impl Token {
    fn new(token_type: TokenType, start_position: usize, end_position: usize) -> Token {
        Token { token_type, start_position, end_position }
    }
}

fn keyword(string: &str) -> String {
    String::from(string)
}

fn has_previous_char(string: &str, position: usize, character: char) -> bool {
    match string.chars().nth(position - 1) {
        Some(c) => c == character,
        None => false
    }
}

fn char_is_whitespace(character: char) -> bool {
    character == ' ' || character == '\n' || character == '\t'
}

fn parse(input: String) -> Vec<Token> {
    let mut tokens: Vec<Token> = Vec::new();
    let mut position: usize = 0;
    let mut end_of_input = false;
    let keywords = [
        keyword("import"),
        keyword("as"),
    ];

    while !end_of_input {
        if position >= input.chars().count() {
            end_of_input = true;
        }

        let character = match input.chars().nth(position) {
            Some(c) => c,
            _ => panic!("Fatal error: No character available at the position {}", position)
        };

        if character == '@' && (position == 0 || has_previous_char(&input, position, '\n')) {
            tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::CommandOperator, position, position));
            position += 1;
            continue;
        }

        if character == ' ' || character == '\n' || character == '\t' {
            position += 1;
            continue;
        }

        if character == '"' {
            let mut str = String::from("");
            position += 1;

            for string_character in input[position..].chars() {
                if string_character == '"' {
                    if input.chars().nth(position - 1) == Some('\\') {
                        str.push_str("\"");
                        position += 2;
                    } else {
                        tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::Str(str.clone()), position - str.chars().count() - 1, position));
                        position += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    str.push_str(&string_character.to_string());
                    position += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        let alphanumeric_re = Regex::new(r"[[:alpha:]]").unwrap();

        let constant_re = Regex::new(r"[A-Za-z0-9_]").unwrap();

        if alphanumeric_re.is_match(&character.to_string()) {
            for word in keywords.iter() {
                if &input[position..position + word.chars().count()] == word {
                    tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::Keyword(word.clone()), position, position + word.chars().count() - 1));
                    position += word.chars().count();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if constant_re.is_match(&character.to_string()) {
            let mut constant = String::from("");

            for constant_character in input[position..].chars() {
                let constant_character_as_string = &constant_character.to_string();

                if char_is_whitespace(character) || !constant_re.is_match(constant_character_as_string) {
                    if constant.chars().count() > 0 {
                        tokens.push(Token::new(TokenType::Const(constant.clone()), position - constant.chars().count(), position - 1));
                    }
                    break;
                } else if constant_re.is_match(constant_character_as_string) {
                    constant.push_str(constant_character_as_string);
                    position += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        println!("{:#?}", tokens);
    }

    tokens
}

fn main() {
    let input = String::from("@import \"intro.txt\" as intro1\n@import \"goals.txt\" as goals_section");
    println!("{:#?}", parse(input));
}
```

I tried to put a `println!` statement in the first check of the `while` loop and it **is** `true`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), and your code does not appear minimized. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster Oops, my bad. I have added it now.

Comment: That doesn't _appear_ any smaller; it seems to be the same content in the playground.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not quite sure how to minimize it. Should I remove all the `structs`, `enums` and functions which are not directly related to the issue (I have read that part on the link you posted but it's still not quite clear to me what should I do here specifically)?

Comment: *which are not directly related to the issue* — yes. And replace variables with hard-coded things when possible, shrink your input to your parser, remove parts of the parser that aren't called, etc.

Comment: You set `end_of_input` but nothing about that stops the loop so `input.chars().nth(position)` is still going to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while !end_of_input {` runs any time execution of the loop returns to the top of the loop. Your snippet

```
if position >= input.chars().count() {
  end_of_input = true;
}
```

will assign `end_of_input`, but that does not stop

```
input.chars().nth(position)
```

from executing with `position` pointing at the end of the string.

It seems like potentially you'd instead want that line to be

```
if position >= input.chars().count() {
  break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding `break` there but then the last token is not added to the vector of tokens.

Comment: Then refactor your code to not panic in that case since panicing is not the right thing to do.